# surjective homomorphism between principal ideal rings

Tags: linear-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, continuous-homomorphisms

I asked this question before but did not get an answer, I tried solving it myself and I think I'm heading somewhere, I just need a push in the right direction.

Let $\phi: R \to S$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings.
Suppose that $\phi$ is surjective and that $R$ is a principal ideal ring (Meaning all the ideals are principal ideals, spanned only by 1 term).

Show that $S$ is also a principal ideal ring.

***My "psuedo" solution***

We know that $R/ker(\phi)$ is isomorphic to $Im(S) = S$ ($\phi$ is surjective).

We also know that $ker(\phi)$ is an ideal, and we know that if $R$ is a principal ideal ring and $I$ is a prime ideal then $R/I$ is also a principal ideal ring.

So I wanted to show that $ker(\phi)$ is a prime ideal, that would solve the question. But it doesn't have to be...Let's look at $ab \in ker(\phi)$:

$ab \in ker(\phi)$ implies $\phi(ab) = 0$ which implies $\phi(a)\phi(b)=0$ which implies $a \in ker(\phi)$ or $b \in ker(\phi)$ IF AND ONLY IF $S$ has no zero divisors. We we're not given that. it could be possible to find $\phi(a),\phi(b) \in S$ such that their product is zero and neither of them is zero.

And that is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring S is a principal ideal ring, but not necessarily a principal ideal DOMAIN.
If $J$ is an ideal in $S$, then $I=\phi^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal of $R$.  So $I$ is principal,
generated by some $x\in R$.   Given $j\in J$, write $\phi^{-1}(j)=ax$ for some $a\in R$. Then
$j=\phi(a)\phi(x$) showing that $J$ is generated by $\phi(x)$.

Comment: Sir, why $\phi^{-1}(j)=ax$ for some $a\in R$? Why $\phi^{-1}(j)\in I$? $\phi^{-1}(j)$ must be set. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is true is $S$ contains zero-divisors. Consider the following surjective morphism
$$k[X]\to k[X]/(X^2),$$
where $k$ is a field.

EDIT: In view of Jeremy's answer, I will add that if we replace *principal ideal ring* by *principal ideal domain*, we have counter-examples, as my answer shows.

Comment: We were not given that S doesn't have zero divisors. We can't assume that. It needs to be proven.

Comment: @OriaGruber I saw that. But since I thought $R$ and $S$ were PIDs (Jeremy's answer above shows why the distinction is important), I was saying that there exist counter-examples.

Comment: @OriaGruber And to be fair, in view of your question, it seems you were also confused by the distinction.